# ItemsControl with horizontal orientation

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

Do you know any controls inherited from the ItemsControl that have horizontal orientation of items?

Answer (score 528, accepted):

Simply change the panel used to host the items:

```
<ItemsControl ...>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Don't you need to add IsItemsHost="True" to the StackPanel ?

Comment: I believe that's only necessary if you're re-templating the entire control. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel.aspx

Comment: Answer also holds for Silverlight

Comment: how to do this in a resource file?

Comment: To do this in a resource file, you need to set the x:Key key

Comment: I wish you could just do something like `StackPanel.Orientation="Horizontal"` in the main tag!

Comment: Just to make it absolutely clear for everyone (even XAML/WPF/UWP newcomers), you should ADD the `ItemsControl.ItemsPanel` to your `ItemsControl`, you should NOT REPLACE your `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate` with the `ItemsControl.ItemsPanel`

Comment: Answer also holds on Avalonia

Answer (score 37):

While the promoted answer is great, here's an alternative if you want the items to stretch.

```
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>                              
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <UniformGrid Rows="1" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

Comment: If you're using UWP, you'll need UWP-UniformGrid from here: https://github.com/rickapps/UWP-UniformGrid-Control. I just implemented it plus NielW's solution above. Really easy and solves the problem.

Answer (score 12):

This is an example of how to do horizontal scrolling within an ItemsControl.

Firstly the main window viewmodel class used to get/set the list of items we wish to display.

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ItemsControl
{
   public class Item
   {
      public Item(string title)
      {
         Title = title;
      }

      public string Title { get; set; }
   }

   public class MainWindowViewModel
   {
      public MainWindowViewModel()
      {
         Titles = new List<Item>()
         {
            new Item("Slide 1"),
            new Item("Slide 2"),
            new Item("Slide 3"),
            new Item("Slide 4"),
            new Item("Slide 5"),
            new Item("Slide 6"),
            new Item("Slide 7"),
            new Item("Slide 8"),
         };
      }

      public List<Item> Titles { get; set; }
   }
}
```

The main window xaml for the view:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
    <Window x:Class="ItemsControl.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ItemsControl"      
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="400">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid Margin="5">
        <ScrollViewer
            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">

            <ItemsControl
                x:Name="SearchResultList"                
                ItemsSource="{Binding Titles}">

                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border
                            Margin="5"
                            BorderThickness="1"
                            BorderBrush="Aqua">

                            <TextBlock
                                Text="{Binding Title}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"                               
                                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                FontSize="12"
                                TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                TextAlignment="Center"
                                FontWeight="DemiBold"  
                                Width="150"
                                Height="150" />
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Depending on how high/wide your client area is, this will result in this kind of layout, overflow items scrolled horizontally:

[image]

More details can be found at this blog link, including an example on how to do the scrolling vertically:

http://www.technical-recipes.com/2017/how-to-orient-wrappanel-items-within-itemscontrol-lists-vertically-and-horizontally/

Answer (score 10):

The top answer is good, but I couldn't get it to work with UserControls. If you need UserControls, this should help.

[ItemsControl with Horizontal Usercontrols](http://social.expression.microsoft.com/Forums/en/blend/thread/79aceb00-59ab-479f-8980-00e84795f23e)

My Version:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate2">
        <StackPanel>
            <uc:MyUserControl MinWidth="20" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0.1" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ItemsPanelTemplate1">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <ItemsControl x:Name="list_MyControls"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  Margin="0,8,0,0"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate2}"
                  ItemsPanel="{StaticResource ItemsPanelTemplate1}" />
</StackPanel>
```

To bind to data, you will need to add an `ItemsSource` to the `ItemsControl` in the XAML or code behind. Also note that `uc:` would be the `xmlns:uc="NamespaceOfMyControl"` declared at the top of the file.

Comment: I'm not used to using WPF, so maybe what i will say is very basic stuff. I found out that inside an UserControl you should use "UserControl.Resources" instead of "Window.Resources". Anyway, thanks for the great answer, solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

For a long list with hundreds or even thousands of items, you should better use [VirtualizingStackPanel](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/wpf-layout-virtualizingstackpanel/) to avoid performance issues.

Comment: this is an 11 year old question, I would hope it's been resolved already ;)

Comment: Just added this comment to make the solution more complete :) Because you know, this WPF, it's so unfriendly framework, sometimes unpredictable, and with latest VS 2019 crashes so annoying XD