# Buttons in a binded ItemsControl should be horizontal

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, itemscontrol

I have this XAML:

```
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Raccourcis}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Content="{Binding Contenu}" Width="25" Height="25" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </WrapPanel>
```

On the context side, I have that:

```
    public ObservableCollection<Raccourci> Raccourcis
    {
        get
        {
            return m_raccourcis;
        }

        set
        {
            m_raccourcis = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Raccourcis");
        }
    }

public class Raccourci
{
    public string Contenu { get; set; }
}
```

I just want to have buttons displayed horizontally but I get:

[image: screenshot]

I'd like to have them with an horizontal alignement. Unfortunatly this answer [ItemsControl with horizontal orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052342/itemscontrol-with-horizontal-orientation) does not seem relevant in my case...

Comment: why the linked Q&A is not relevant?

Comment: @ASh: actually my first test was bad (my fault). Actually the linked Q&A answers perfectly my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This XAML fixes the problem:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Raccourcis}">

    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
              <Button Content="{Binding Contenu}" Width="25" Height="25" />
         </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

</ItemsControl>
```

[image: result]