# Binding text to nested member in object in array

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, nested

I challenged myself to make my application in WPF, I never tried before :)

Maybe it's obvious but I don't understand where is my mistake.

My **RecipePage** display correctly the part `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}">` but nothing for `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Details[0].PieceName}">` *(or 1)*

I have no error, just nothing.

Is it caused by `Recipe.AddDetails()` which no send any `PropertyChanged` event ?

Thank you in advance for your help :)

**RecipePage.xaml**

```
...
<Grid>
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="112" Height="29" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="PRECEDENT" Margin="10"/>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource h1}"></TextBlock>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Details[0].PieceName}" Style="{StaticResource h2}"></TextBlock>
            ...
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Details[1].PieceName}" Style="{StaticResource h2}"></TextBlock>
            ...
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
...
```

**RecipePage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class RecipePage : Page
{

    public RecipePage(Recipe recipe)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = recipe;
    }
}
```

**Page creation:**

```
    private void OnBourguignonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var recipe = new Recipe("BOURGUIGNON ou SAUTE", 190, "images/recipes/rotideboeuf.jpg");
        recipe.AddDetails(new RecipeDetails("paleron", 6, 31));
        recipe.AddDetails(new RecipeDetails("sauté maigre", 190, 221));
        ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow)?.NavigationFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(new RecipePage(recipe));
    }
```

**Recipe.cs**

```
public class Recipe : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int MeatWeightPerPers { get; set; }

    public string ImagePath { get; set; }

    public RecipeDetails[] Details = new RecipeDetails[]{};

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Recipe(string name, int meatWeight, string image)
    {
        Name = name;
        MeatWeightPerPers = meatWeight;
        ImagePath = image;
    }

    public void AddDetails(RecipeDetails details)
    {
        Details.Append(details);
    }
}
```

**RecipeDetails.cs**

```
public class RecipeDetails : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string PieceName { get; set; }
    public int PieceWeightPerCow { get; set; }
    public int NbPersPerCow { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public RecipeDetails(string pieceName, int pieceWeightPerCow, int nbPersPerCow)
    {
        PieceName = pieceName;
        PieceWeightPerCow= pieceWeightPerCow;
        NbPersPerCow = nbPersPerCow;
    }
}
```

**FodyWeavers.xml** (installed)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Weavers xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="FodyWeavers.xsd">
  <PropertyChanged />
</Weavers>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that adding an element to `Details` doesn't raise the `CollectionChanged` event. This event is automatically raised by the `ObservableCollection` when it's changed, so you'll want to use that instead of an array:

```
public class Recipe : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int MeatWeightPerPers { get; set; }

    public string ImagePath { get; set; }

    // Instead of array, use ObservableCollection
    public ObservableCollection<RecipeDetails> Details { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Recipe(string name, int meatWeight, string image)
    {
        Name = name;
        MeatWeightPerPers = meatWeight;
        ImagePath = image;

        // Initialize Details collection
        Details = new ObservableCollection<RecipeDetails>();
    }

    public void AddDetails(RecipeDetails details)
    {
        Details.Add(details);
    }
}
```

Since `Details` is some kind of list, you'll probably want to display it using an `ItemsControl` rather than using individual `TextBlock`s:

```
...
<Grid>
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="112" Height="29" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="PRECEDENT" Margin="10"/>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource h1}"></TextBlock>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Details}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding PieceName}" Style="{StaticResource h2}" />
                            ...
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
...
```

Comment: Do you know why my details `items` are stacked vertically instead of horizontally while my `ItemsControl` parent panel is an `<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">` ?

Comment: Your `StackPanel` only orients its contents, not the contents of the `ItemsPanel`. But there's a solution: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1052512/1383366

Comment: Oh ok ! I thought `ItemsControl` generate only items in the parent container. Thank you